# ¿Cómo subir archivos pesados en fragmentos (chunks)?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un formulario el cual manda cuantos archivos pongas a una carpeta local. Está funcionando solamente en local, pero es cuestión de cambiar de rutas, nada mas.

**index.php**
*Página principal, solamente tiene la variable de sesión para controlar errores mediante el php*

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['message']) && $_SESSION['message'])
    {
      printf('<b>%s</b>', $_SESSION['message']);
      unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }
?>

  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()" multiple size="50"><br>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-progressbar" value="Upload" style="visibility:hidden">
  </form>

<template id="temp_prog">
  <div id="demo">
    <h3 class="txt_file_num">  </h3>
    <p class="txt_file_name"></p>
    <p class="txt_file_size"></p>
    <progress class="progressBar" value="0" max="100""></progress>
  </div>
</template>
```

**JS**
*Ya está hecho, pero a la hora de mandar las cosas por el PHP, si es demasiado grande, casca error*

```
let ary = [];

function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  let file = _("file1");

  if('files' in file){
    if(file.files.length == 0){
      console.log("Select one or more files");

    } else {
      for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){
        //request y declaracion iterada de files
        let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let x = file.files[i];

        //despliegue del temp
        let txt = createElement();
        document.body.append(txt);

        //push en array
        ary.push(x);

        //logs
        if ('name' in x) {
          txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_name')[0].innerHTML = 'Name: '+x.name;
        }
        if ('size' in x) {
          txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_size')[0].innerHTML = 'Size: '+x.size;
        }

        let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];

        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file1", x);
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{progressHandler(event, bar)}, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "upload.php"); 
        ajax.send(formdata);

      }
    }
  }
}

function progressHandler(event, bar) {

  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  let percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;

  bar.value = Math.round(percent);

  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";

}

function completeHandler(event) {
  ary.shift();
  console.log('completado');

  if(ary.length == 0){
    //_('btn-progressbar').click();
  }
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}

function createElement(){
  let dv = document.createElement('div');
      dv.setAttribute('class', 'demo');
  let p1 = document.createElement('p');
      p1.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_name');
  let p2 = document.createElement('p');
      p2.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_size');
  let pr = document.createElement('progress');
      pr.setAttribute('class', 'progressBar');
      pr.setAttribute('value', '0');
      pr.setAttribute('max', '100');

      dv.append(p1);
      dv.append(p2);
      dv.append(pr);

  return dv;
}
```

**upload.php**
*El origen de la discordia. *

```
<?php
session_start();

$message = ''; 
    
  if (isset($_FILES['file1']) /*&& $_FILES['file1']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK*/){

    // detalles del archivo
    $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
    $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));

    $chunk_size = 5120;
    $upload_start = 0;

    // verificador de extensiones
    $allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'txt', 'xls', 'doc', 'pdf', '7z', 'mp4', 'img', 'php', 'iso');

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)){
      // directory in which the uploaded file will be moved
      $uploadFileDir = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
      $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $fileName;

      if($fileSize < $chunk_size){//Comprueba si tiene mas de 5MB
        
        $handle = fopen($fileTmpPath, "rb");
        $fp = fopen($uploadFileDir, "w");

        $contents = fread($handle, $chunk_size);
        die($contents);
        fwrite($fp, $contents);
        $upload_start += strlen($contents);
        fseek($handle, $upload_start);

        fclose($handle);
        fclose($fp);

        $message = 'Archivo desfragmentado y reacoplado correctamente.';

      } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)){//Mueve archivo al directorio
          $message ='Archivo subido correctamente.';
        } else {
          $message = 'Error al subir el archivo.';
        }
      }
    } else {
      $message = 'Upload failed.';
    }
  } else {
    $message = 'Hubo un error al comprobar variables.';
  }
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
header("Location: image-loader.php");
/*
<?php
session_start();

$message = ''; 

  if (isset($_FILES['file1']) /*&& $_FILES['file1']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
  {

    // get details of the uploaded file
    $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
    $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));

    // sanitize file-name
    $newFileName = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;

    // check if file has one of the following extensions
    $allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'txt', 'xls', 'doc', 'pdf', '7z', 'mp4', 'img');

    echo $fileTmpPath; die;

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions))
    {
      // directory in which the uploaded file will be moved
      $uploadFileDir = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
      $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $newFileName;

      if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)) 
      {
        $message ='File is successfully uploaded.';
      }
      else 
      {
        $message = 'There was some error moving the file to upload directory. Please make sure the upload directory is writable by web server.';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $message = 'Upload failed. Allowed file types: ' . implode(',', $allowedfileExtensions);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $message = 'There is some error in the file upload. Please check the following error.<br>';
    $message .= 'Error:' . $_FILES['file1']['error'];
  }
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
header("Location: image-loader.php");
?>
```

He intentado hacer un **"chunk uploader"** en el que fragmento el archivo en pequeños trozos de 5MB, ya que si mando algo con más de 5MB al formulario, casca.

He seguido un tutorial que hacen esta jugada:

```
if($fileSize < $chunk_size){//Comprueba si tiene mas de 5MB
        
        $handle = fopen($fileTmpPath, "rb");
        $fp = fopen($uploadFileDir, "w");

        $contents = fread($handle, $chunk_size);
        die($contents);
        fwrite($fp, $contents);
        $upload_start += strlen($contents);
        fseek($handle, $upload_start);

        fclose($handle);
        fclose($fp);

        $message = 'Archivo desfragmentado y reacoplado correctamente.';

      }
```

Pero se la salta a la torera. Me gustaría saber cómo poder fragmentar el archivo en pequeños trozos y subirlos poco a poco.

Comment: Debes realizar modificaciones tanto en Javascript para enviar por partes y en PHP para recibir cada parte y, solo hasta que se hayan subido todas, unirlas para guardar en un solo archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El bucle ya está correctamente controlado:

```
var chunk, txt, start, part, BYTES_PER_CHUNK, end;

function selectFile(){
    let file = _("file1");

    if('files' in file){
        for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){
            let x = file.files[i];
            start = 0;
            part = 0;
            BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576;

            //despliegue del temp
            txt = createElement();
            document.body.append(txt);

            //logs
            if ('name' in x) {
                txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_name')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Name:</strong> '+x.name;
            }
            if ('size' in x) {
                txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_size')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Size:</strong> '+x.size;
            }            

            uploadComplete(x);
        }
    }
}

function uploadFile(chunkFile, part, x){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{uploadProgress(event, bar, x)}, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php"+"?"+"file="+x.name+"&num=" + part);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file1", chunkFile);
    xhr.send(fd);
    return;
}

function uploadComplete(x) {
    let pol =[];
    start = 0;
    end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    part = 0;
    while( start < x.size ) {
        chunk = x.slice(start, end);
        console.log(start);
        uploadFile(chunk, part, x);
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        part++;
        pol.push({part:part,start:start,end:end});
    }
    console.log(pol);
}

function uploadProgress(event, bar, x) {
    //let total_size = x.size;
    let slice = parseInt(x.size/(1024*1024));
    


    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
    let percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    bar.value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function uploadFailed(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload failed";
}
  
function uploadCanceled(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload canceled";
}

function createElement(){
    let dv = document.createElement('div');
        dv.setAttribute('class', 'demo');
    let p1 = document.createElement('p');
        p1.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_name');
    let p2 = document.createElement('p');
        p2.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_size');
    let pr = document.createElement('progress');
        pr.setAttribute('class', 'progressBar');
        pr.setAttribute('value', '0');
        pr.setAttribute('max', '100');
  
        dv.append(p1);
        dv.append(p2);
        dv.append(pr);
  
    return dv;
  }

function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
  }
```